# Deleting a pod and all of its files from a project

Tags: cocoapods

So I'm working on a project and I had installed RealmSwift as my DB but later on I figured I can just use a plist to store my data, I went to the pod file, I erased pod 'RealmSwift' and went on terminal to uninstall my pod, everything went well. But my question is, is there a way to fully delete a pod file from a project and revert the project from an xcworkspace to an xcode project? the Pod file still shows under the name of my project, and I feel like submitting a project like that is not clean.

Comment: Maybe looking at `pod deintegrate` ?

Comment: after running pod deintegrate would it be okay to just delete these left over empty pod files? @Larme